# Runtime InvalidCastException with implicit cast operator

Tags: c#, vb.net, implicit-conversion

I have a C# library that internal clients configure with VB.Net

Their scripts are throwing an `InvalidCastException` where they really shouldn't.

So the code is something like this (massively simplified):

```
//C#3
public class Foo {

    public static implicit operator Foo ( Bar input )
    { 
        return new Foo( input.Property1, input.Property2 ); 
    }
}
```

Then in their VB.Net (again massively simplified):

```
Dim fc = New FooCollection()
Dim b as Bar = GetBar()

fc(fooIndex) = b 'throws InvalidCastException at runtime!
```

If I add a breakpoint inside the implicit/widening operator it's never reached.

If I remove the implicit operator it won't compile.

If I execute the equivalent statement in C#:

```
var fc = new FooCollection();
Bar b = GetBar();

fc[fooIndex] = b //it works!
```

Strange - it looks like the VB.net compiler can find the cast operator but it's lost at runtime. Surely the VB and C# IL will be pretty similar here?

The VB.net code is dynamically compiled - the compile happens the first time a user logs into the app. it's being compiled as VB.Net against .Net 3.5, and I'm not using any COM interop.

Any ideas?

Comment: Dim b as Bar = GetBar()
Try to use this way: Dim b = GetBar()

Comment: Opps, delete a comment above, just missed a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd try and mark a C# assembly as `CLSCompliant(true)` to see if this generates any warnings on `implicit operator Foo`.

Aha, [here](http://pdkm.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!D1DDEC9FF002FB8C!700.entry) it is:

> The problem is that VB.NET simply doesn't call `op_Implicit`/`op_Explicit` functions exposed by the C# code. Delving into the Visual Basic engine you can see that under the covers it use `ICovertible` to do all of its conversions.

Comment: `IConvertible` does all the system value type conversions. I thought that in VB.Net you could do `Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal input As Bar) As Foo` and it would be the same as the `public static implicit operator Foo ( Bar input )`

Comment: @Anton, Good find man. Since VB doesn't call the op_Implicit  functions it looks like VB will never be able to call these things in the same way as C#.  Which is crazy, and yet another reason I won't touch VB.Net unless I need to...(Too many quirks with it and things C# supports, but it doesn't...)

Comment: I don't the above link works, here is revised link; http://pauliom.com/2007/07/01/support-implicitexplicit-conversion-in-c-for-vb-net/